# Crashing when changing label text

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set a label depending on the UserDefault value but It's crashing with the error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file

So, first time I run it the app does NOT crash using this code:

**MainActivity**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getAllVehicles()

}

func getAllVehicles(){

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if defaults.object(forKey: "currentCar") != nil{
        currentCar = defaults.string(forKey: "currentCar")

        registrationPlate.text = currentCar
    }
}
```

So the application is setting the label to it's UserDefault and that does work, but when I'm trying to change it (Just to mention, it's from another class/viewcontroller)

**ChooseCarViewController**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let car = carsArray[indexPath.row]

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(car, forKey: "currentCar")

    if let storyboard = storyboard{
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController

        vc.getAllVehicles()

        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

}
```

So by any reason I can NOT change the name when calling the method.

I've also tried to set it directly by using

> vc.registrationPlate.text = car

Just to mention:
I've tried to print out "car" and it does return the correct value.
I've also tried to print the "currentCar" in MainActivity after calling the method and It's returning the correct car. But the textfield cannot be changed because of unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: the text field is nil because it is not loaded yet and is not visible to user.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri So how can that be fixed? Using ViewDidAppear? But how comes it's not loaded since the ViewController is still in the back stack right?

Comment: Instead of calling vc.getAllVehicle() from your ChooseCarViewController, you should call it in viewWillAppear of your MainActivity class. That will do your work.

Comment: @KeshuRai Do you mean viewDidAppear? I tried it by adding "viewDidAppear" in MainViewController and inside that one I'm calling "getAllVehicles". Still no process after I "dismiss" view controller B

Comment: No, I mean viewWillAppear only. try it once

Comment: how are you showing MainViewController?

Answer (score 0):

All UI stuff that you build with storyboard are `optional` and they are implicitly unwrapped using `!`. For example

```
@IBOutlet weak var registrationPlate: UILabel! // <- Do you see the `!` here?
```

So as `UIViewController` default template suggests, you should

> Do any additional setup after loading the view.

The first function you can do it in is `viewDidLoad`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

If you initialize a view controller from another one it doesn't grantees that all outlets are automatically have been assigned (yet).

First of all you must use the initializer from the `storyboard` or from the `xib` file to have the correct initializer set the outlets.

Then you should wait for `viewDidLoad`. (You can use `vc.loadView()` to force it, but it's not recommended at all)

---

In your code, you are using `storyboard.instantiateViewController...` that creates another instance and since you are just `dismiss`ing the view, it's not needed at all! Because the previous controller is already loaded and it exist in the memory.

And note that you are using reading the `registrationPlate` inside `getAllVehicles` and it should be done after view is loaded. So you can extract this part from it and move it somewhere after view gets loaded.

Comment: But on the second view controller I'm using "self.dismiss", will the "viewDidLoad" load again on ViewController 1? once the second view controller is dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the protocol / delegate pattern.

Define a protocol:

```
protocol ChangeCarDelegate: AnyObject {
    func changeCar(_ newCar: String)
}
```

Have your Main view controller "conform" to that protocol:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, ChangeCarDelegate {

    func changeCar(_ newCar: String) {
        currentCar = newCar
        registrationPlate.text = currentCar
    }

}
```

When you present the Choose Car VC, assign its ChangeCarDelegate property:

```
@IBAction func showChooseCar(_ sender: Any) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChooseCarVC") as? ChooseCarViewController {
        vc.changeCarDelegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using a Storyboard created Segue to present the Choose Car VC:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ChooseCarViewController {
        vc.changeCarDelegate = self
    }
}
```

When you select a car from the table, tell the delegate of the new selection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let car = carsArray[indexPath.row]
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(car, forKey: "currentCar")

    // communicate with the delegate
    changeCarDelegate?.changeCar(car)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

Here is a full set of classes for a simple "Main" VC with a label and a button. Tapping the button presents "ChooseCar" VC, which has a table of cars.

```
protocol ChangeCarDelegate {
    func changeCar(_ newCar: String)
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController, ChangeCarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var registrationPlate: UILabel!

    var currentCar: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getAllVehicles()
    }

    func getAllVehicles(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if defaults.object(forKey: "currentCar") != nil{
            currentCar = defaults.string(forKey: "currentCar") ?? ""
            registrationPlate.text = currentCar
        }
    }

    @IBAction func showChooseCar(_ sender: Any) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChooseCarVC") as? ChooseCarViewController {
            vc.changeCarDelegate = self
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // or, if you are using a Storyboard created Segue to present the Choose Car VC
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ChooseCarViewController {
            vc.changeCarDelegate = self
        }
    }

    func changeCar(_ newCar: String) {
        currentCar = newCar
        registrationPlate.text = currentCar
    }

}

class ChooseCarViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    weak var changeCarDelegate: ChangeCarDelegate?

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var carsArray: [String] = [
        "Ford",
        "Honda",
        "Toyota",
        "Chrysler",
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return carsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CarCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = carsArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let car = carsArray[indexPath.row]
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(car, forKey: "currentCar")
        changeCarDelegate?.changeCar(car)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not misuse `UserDefaults` to share data between controllers, pass the data directly.

The crash occurs because the outlet is not connected yet when the label is accessed.

The solution is to create a temporary variable in `MainActivity` and assign the value to the label in `viewDidLoad`

```
var currentCar = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registrationPlate.text = currentCar
}
```

Assign the car to the temporary variable in `ChooseCarViewController` and you have to present the vc

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    let car = carsArray[indexPath.row]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(car, forKey: "currentCar")

    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as? MainViewController {
        vc.currentCar = car
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**As you have mentioned this in your comments!!**

```
@TejaNandamuri So how can that be fixed? Using ViewDidAppear? 
But how comes it's not loaded since the ViewController is still in the back stack right?
```

In this code, vc is not pointing to the same view controller which is behind in the stack. It is creating a new view controller. In new vc, textfield is not yet loaded.

```
if let storyboard = storyboard{
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController

    vc.getAllVehicles()

    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

**Use delegates to achieve what you want.**

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to assigning a nullable value to label, handle null using `guard let` or `if let`
like below

```
    guard let currentCar = defaults.string(forKey: "currentCar") else{
     registrationPlate.text = ""
     return
    }

    registrationPlate.text = currentCar ?? ""
```

Comment: Well, in this case the this might always return "", otherwise it would not crash right?

Comment: yes, if you want to not return use if let with else to give a default value to label\